# Unable to play .mp4 video file using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I am using the `AVPlayer` to play the video from url.

```
func playVideoFromUrl(urlString: String){

        let videoURL = URL(string: urlString)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player

        let delegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        delegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
```

The `url of video`:- "http://gsn-input-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/public/video/00229/9229d4ad2a0c547e7bfa51e3fbef806f.mp4"

I am not getting any warning at console. Below is the screenshot of simulator. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Video is playing, I just checked it. There is no issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have accomplished what you've wanted to do. Here is my approach:
First import AVFoundation, AVKit(I believe you had) then I have configured my viewcontroller like this

```
   @IBOutlet weak var avPlayerView: UIView! // drag a UIView to view controller
   var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()
   var avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let videoURL = URL(string: "http://gsn-input-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/public/video/00229/9229d4ad2a0c547e7bfa51e3fbef806f.mp4")

    self.playVideo(url: videoURL!)

}
```

playVideo function is configured like below

```
  func playVideo(url: URL) {
       self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
       self.avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
       self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.videoPlayer
       avPlayerViewController.view.frame = avPlayerView.frame
       self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController)
       self.view.addSubview((avPlayerViewController.view)!)

   }
```

Open your info.plist as Source Code[image]

then add this to info.plist

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

screen shot is given below

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work. Please accept my up vote. Thanks!

Comment: Just add an "s" and use https to avoid all that NSAppTransportSecurity as it's not recommended to set that to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding arbitrary load flag in your info.plist file as i see the url is a **HTTP** url and to make the **HTTP** url work, we need to specify it in app transportation security via info.plist as follows

[image]

Please try doing this as video is working perfectly fine with you code.

Read following document for more info on [App Transportation Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I still have same issue, even after making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out that a device running iOS 14 using `AVPlayer` cannot play `.mp4` files. A compatible video format that works on `AVPlayer` is `.mov`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have had a trouble playing `.mp4` files. When I made the URL end with `.mp4` it works.